# urllib2 connection timed out error

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to open a page using urllib2 but i keep getting connection timed out errors.
The line which i  am using is: 
`f = urllib2.urlopen(url)`

exact error is:

`URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>`

Comment: can you load the url in browser?

Comment: yes, the url loads in the browser. I think the problem is maybe with my connection settings. How does the python urllib2 connect to internet?

Comment: I was behind proxy and now i am not. Only change I made was to remove http_proxy and https_proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`urllib2` respects robots.txt. Many sites block the default `User-Agent`.

Try adding a new `User-Agent`, by creating `Request` objects & using them as arguments for `urlopen`:

```
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com/')
request.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux i686)')

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Several detailed walk-throughs are available, such as http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/urllib2/

Comment: It seems unlikely that it respects robots.txt.  This would require urllib2 to do an additional network request to grab the file.  Sites may well block certain user agents though, but this is a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

As a general strategy, open wireshark and watch the traffic generated by `urllib2.urlopen(url)`. You may be able to see where the error is coming from.