# How to get an HTML file using Python?

Tags: python, html, webclient

I am not very familiar with Python. I am trying to extract the artist names (for a start :)) from the following page: http://www.infolanka.com/miyuru_gee/art/art.html.

How do I retrieve the page? My two main concerns are; what functions to use and how to filter out useless links from the page?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Example using urlib and lxml.html:

```
import urllib
from lxml import html

url = "http://www.infolanka.com/miyuru_gee/art/art.html"
page = html.fromstring(urllib.urlopen(url).read())

for link in page.xpath("//a"):
    print "Name", link.text, "URL", link.get("href")

output >>
    [('Aathma Liyanage', 'athma.html'),
     ('Abewardhana Balasuriya', 'abewardhana.html'),
     ('Aelian Thilakeratne', 'aelian_thi.html'),
     ('Ahamed Mohideen', 'ahamed.html'),
    ]
```

Comment: in python 3 you should import urllib.request and use urllib.request.urlopen function. see http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen

Comment: urllib is outdated in this day and age and should be using the requests library or something that handles the modern day issues.

Answer (score 7):

I think "eyquem" way would be my choice too, but I like to use **httplib2** instead of **urllib**. *urllib2* is too low level lib for this work.

`import httplib2, re

pat = re.compile('<DT><a href="[^"]+">(.+?)</a>')
http = httplib2.Http()
headers, body = http.request("http://www.infolanka.com/miyuru_gee/art/art.html")

li = pat.findall(body)
print li`

Answer (score 6):

1. Use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to get the page.
2. Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the HTML (the page) and get what you want!

Answer (score 6):

Check this my friend

```
import urllib.request

import re

pat = re.compile('<DT><a href="[^"]+">(.+?)</a>')

url = 'http://www.infolanka.com/miyuru_gee/art/art.html'

sock = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")

li = pat.findall(sock)

print(li)
```

Answer (score 4):

Or go straight forward:

```
import urllib

import re
pat = re.compile('<DT><a href="[^"]+">(.+?)</a>')

url = 'http://www.infolanka.com/miyuru_gee/art/art.html'
sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
li = pat.findall(sock.read())
sock.close()

print li
```

Answer (score 1):

And respect [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) and throttle your requests :)

(Apparently urllib2 does already according to this [helpful SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197299/urllib2-connection-timed-out-error)).

Comment: Is it illegal to not do so? ^.^

Comment: No, unless I misinterpret the multiple negatives there. :)

Answer (score 1):

A more concise answer adapted to Python 3.x and using `requests` and `bs4`. There are two questions though in the original question. First,  how to obtain the html:

```
import requests
html = requests.get("http://www.infolanka.com/miyuru_gee/art/art.html").content
```

Second, how to obtain artists name list:

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
artist_list = []
for i in soup.find_all("a"):
    if i.parent.name == "dt":
        artist_list.append(i.contents[0])
print(artist_list)
```

Output:

```
['Aathma Liyanage',
 'Abewardhana Balasuriya',
 'Aelian Thilakeratne',
 'Ahamed Mohideen',
 'Ajantha Nakandala',
 'Ajith Ambalangoda',
 'Ajith Ariayaratne',
 'Ajith Muthukumarana',
 'Ajith Paranawithana',
...]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Basically,  there's a function call:
>
> > `render_template()`
>
> You can easly return single page or list of pages with it and it reads
>   all files automaticaly from a `your_workspace\templates` .
>
> Example:
>
> > `/root_dir
> >        /templates
> >            /index1.html,
> >            /index2.html 
> >        /other_dir
> >        /`
> >
> > routes.py
> >
> > `@app.route('/')
> >     def root_dir():
> >         return render_template('index1.html')`
> >
> > `@app.route(/<username>)
> >     def root_dir_with_params(username):
> >         retun render_template('index2.html', user=username)`
>
> index1.html - without params
>
> > `<html>    <body>
> >           <h1>Hello guest!</h1>
> >           <button id="getData">Get Data!</button>    </body>    </html>`
>
> index2.html - with params
>
> > `<html>    <body>    <!-- Built-it conditional functions in the framework templates in Flask -->    {% if name %} 
> >           <h1 style="color: red;">Hello {{ user }}!</h1>    {% else %}
> >           <h1>Hello guest.</1>
> >           <button id="getData">Get Data!</button>    </body>    </html>`